# How to only get the last object's text?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building a chat application. I made an if else statement for the text in the message. If the text in the message is equal to a specific text than something should happen. But when I do that, it does that with all the messages that contains that text. Is there a way to only do this action when the last message is equal to that text?

I hope that I explained it as clear as possible. I'm new to Swift :)

This is my code:

```
  if message.text == "Looks" {
        looksContainterView.isHidden = false
        looksSmallText.isHidden = false
        looksTitle.isHidden = false
        looksEmoji.isHidden = false
        shareButton.isHidden = false
    } else {
        looksContainterView.isHidden = true
        looksSmallText.isHidden = true
        looksTitle.isHidden = true
        looksEmoji.isHidden = true
        shareButton.isHidden = true

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of code but here is what I would do:

Change it so the message goes through a function when it's recieved, if the message contains the specific text then give it a flag.

In the message box all the messages with that flag will be given the attributes you desire.